# Why doesn't my reputation change on the meta site?

Tags: support, faq, meta, reputation

Some of my questions and answers have been voted on (both up and down) on this meta site.   Why doesn't my reputation change, like it does on the primary [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) site?

Answer (score 3):

As reported on [Stack Overflow Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/), in the [New Per-Site Metas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) post, which talks of the Stack Exchange 2.0 meta sites:

> **Reputation is always inherited from the parent site.** You cannot gain or lose reputation* on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the reputation graph, and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta.
>   **Voting up or down does not affect reputation.** You are now free to vote purely based on post content, without worrying about how your vote might positively or negatively affect someone's reputation score.